How to multiply matrices and exclude elements based on masking?
I have the following input matrix
inp_tensor = torch.tensor(
        [[0.7860, 0.1115, 0.0000, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725, 0.7980, 0.0000],
        [1.0000, 0.1115, 0.0000, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725, 0.0000, 1.0000]])

and indices of the elements that I want to exclude (in this example they are the zero elements, but they can be any value)
mask_indices = torch.tensor(
[[7, 2],
[2, 6]])

How can I exclude these elements from the multiplication with the following matrix:
my_tensor = torch.tensor(
        [[0.8823, 0.9150, 0.3829],
        [0.9593, 0.3904, 0.6009],
        [0.2566, 0.7936, 0.9408],
        [0.1332, 0.9346, 0.5936],
        [0.8694, 0.5677, 0.7411],
        [0.4294, 0.8854, 0.5739],
        [0.2666, 0.6274, 0.2696],
        [0.4414, 0.2969, 0.8317]])

That is, instead of multiplying it including these values (zeros in this example):
a = torch.mm(inp_tensor, my_tensor)
print(a)
tensor([[1.7866, 2.5468, 1.6330],
        [2.2041, 2.5388, 2.3315]])

I want to exclude the (zero) elements (and the corresponding rows of my_tensor), so they will not participate in the computational graph:
inp_tensor = torch.tensor(
        [[0.7860, 0.1115, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725, 0.7980]]) # remove the elements based on the indices (the zeros here)

my_tensor = torch.tensor(
        [[0.8823, 0.9150, 0.3829],
        [0.9593, 0.3904, 0.6009],
        [0.1332, 0.9346, 0.5936],
        [0.8694, 0.5677, 0.7411],
        [0.4294, 0.8854, 0.5739],
        [0.2666, 0.6274, 0.2696]]) # remove the corresponding zero elements rows

b = torch.mm(inp_tensor, my_tensor)
print(b)
>>> tensor([[1.7866, 2.5468, 1.6330]])

inp_tensor = torch.tensor([[1.0000, 0.1115, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725, 1.0000]]) # remove the elements based on the indices (the zeros here)

my_tensor = torch.tensor(
        [
        [0.8823, 0.9150, 0.3829],                
        [0.9593, 0.3904, 0.6009],
        [0.1332, 0.9346, 0.5936],
        [0.8694, 0.5677, 0.7411],
        [0.4294, 0.8854, 0.5739],
        [0.4414, 0.2969, 0.8317]])  # remove the corresponding zero elements rows

c = torch.mm(inp_tensor, my_tensor)
print(c)
>>> tensor([[2.2041, 2.5388, 2.3315]])
print(torch.cat([b,c]))
>>> tensor([[1.7866, 2.5468, 1.6330],
        [2.2041, 2.5388, 2.3315]])

I need this to be efficient (i.e., no for loops), as my tensors are quite large, and also to maintain the gradient (i.e., if I call optimizer.backward() that the relevant parameters from the computational graph be updated)
Note that each of the rows of inp_tensor have the same number of elements to be removed (e.g., zero elements in this example). Hence, each of the rows of mask_indices will also have the same number of elements (e.g., 2 in this example).

If a given value is equal to 0, then it won't be contributing to the sum. What is the point of excluding zeros from the matrix multiplication then?

@Ivan You are correct that it won't be contributing to the sum, and also the gradients will not be affected for those parameters (since their gradients will be 0). But, I'm developing a new optimizer and those zero multiplications mess with it

I doubt anything should be done here, since excluding zeros makes absolutely no difference. I suppose you meant to exclude them from participating in backward, so as not to mess up your optimizer? In that case, what do you need for the optimizer?

@ihdv Excluding the zeros will actually make a lot difference. I cannot explain the optimizer here, but you are correct that I want to exclude them from the computational graph (hence the backward pass)

@Penguin Based on my experience perhaps it's better to define a new torch Function and modify the gradient computation in its backward, or mask out any gradient affected by these zeros in your optimizer. But without knowing exactly what behavior you want I cannot give more suggestions.

@ihdv Maybe, but that seems like a much more complicated and more potentially error-prone approach than simply not including the parameters in the computational graph in the first place

@Penguin Your updated code works because each of your row of inp_tensor have the same number of zero elements. It this intentional?

@MinhNguyenHoang Yes! Just added it to the question, but this will always be the case -- each of the rows of inp_tensor have the same number of elements to be removed (e.g., zero elements in this example). Hence, each of the rows of mask_indices will also have the same number of elements (e.g., 2 in this example).

It sounds like you want to perform a matmul with specific elements in the inputs excluded from the computational graph. I don't think that's possible without writing your own custom matmul kernel.

@Karl I'm not sure how that would look like, but would appreciate any help at this point

I think, want you need is masked tensor. Please have a look to this documentation. Unfortunately, it does not support matmul for now, but I believe it will be added in future, you may try to open GitHub issue to speed up the process. However, it supports mul and sum operations, you may try to use those to solve your problem.
To create masked tensors you can do following (adapting the code from Rehan Ahmed):
mask_row_ids = torch.arange(mask_indices.shape[0]).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, mask_indices.shape[1])

mask_tensor = torch.ones(inp_tensor.shape).bool()
mask_tensor[mask_row_ids, mask_indices] = False

inp_tensor_masked = torch.masked.masked_tensor(inp_tensor, mask_tensor, requires_grad=True)

mask_tensor = torch.ones(my_tensor.shape).bool()
my_tensor_masked = torch.masked.masked_tensor(my_tensor, mask_tensor, requires_grad=True)

This will give you following tensors:
MaskedTensor(
  [
    [  0.7860,   0.1115,       --,   0.6524,   0.6057,   0.3725,   0.7980,       --],
    [  1.0000,   0.1115,       --,   0.6524,   0.6057,   0.3725,       --,   1.0000]
  ]
)

MaskedTensor(
  [
    [  0.8823,   0.9150,   0.3829],
    [  0.9593,   0.3904,   0.6009],
    [  0.2566,   0.7936,   0.9408],
    [  0.1332,   0.9346,   0.5936],
    [  0.8694,   0.5677,   0.7411],
    [  0.4294,   0.8854,   0.5739],
    [  0.2666,   0.6274,   0.2696],
    [  0.4414,   0.2969,   0.8317]
  ]
)

Then you may try to make them to be the same size, by transposing and repeating, and use mul and sum functions.
Note: numpy also has masked array idea, please have a look here. But the way it performs dot product, is again by replacing with 0s, please see the implementation here. So, you need to make sure whether in future, torch implements it the way you want.
I guess switching back and forth from torch tensor to numpy is not applicable solution for you either.

Did you run this code? I'm getting tensor([[1.5739, 2.0461, 1.4179],         [1.7627, 2.2419, 1.4998]]) which is different than the original answer

I think col_mask_indices is wrong (prints tensor([ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False]), which results in inp_tensor_filtred being tensor([[0.7860, 0.1115, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725],         [1.0000, 0.1115, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725]])

So you need to remove columns from inp_tensor which contains 0s and corresponding rows from my_tensor, right?

mask_indices contains indices of the elements that I want to exclude (in this example they are the zero elements, but they can be any value)

you cannot exclude single element, you can exclude either entire row or column, right? So, in your case mask_indices shows column indices of first and second rows, meaning that you need to remove entire columns, which contains that indices, right? So at the end you will get tensor([[0.7860, 0.1115, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725],         [1.0000, 0.1115, 0.6524, 0.6057, 0.3725]]) for inp_tensor?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For your edit -- Please see other comments and my question -- I do not want to multiply them by 0, I want to exclude them from the computational graph

@Penguin I've edited my answer based on the inputs. Hope, it will help you.

Interesting. You were saying "Then you may try to make them to be the same size, by transposing and repeating, and use mul and sum functions", but that seems to be the main difficulty if you look at my updated with my answer -- repeating the tensor is not efficient and runs out of memory

Right, it is the trickiest part, which I've failed to find the efferent solution. I've then thought to find some function which can do batch multiplication with batch size 1, to do vector-vector multiplication, found torch.bmm but it seems it also not what I exactly tried to find.

Also, I'm getting UserWarning: It is not recommended to create a MaskedTensor with a tensor that requires_grad, so I think this will actually not work because it will remove the gradients

Oh, I didn't get that warning, may be have some warning suppression somewhere. I forgot to add requires_grad=True, in the argument while creating the masked tensor. Now, my_tensor_masked.requires_grad and inp_tensor_masked.requires_grad will have True. But in general my impression is also that this is some new feature, need to be imporved.

I'm wondering if this can work actually. Let's say that inp_tensor does not require grad (so the gradients can still propagate through my_tensor). So you could use inp_tensor_masked. Trying to figure out how to do the multiplication

I think I may have figured the dimensions. Want to move to the chat you started earlier?

Sorry, missed that, I'm now online.

Would this work for you:
mask_row_ids = torch.arange(mask_indices.shape[0]).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, mask_indices.shape[1])

mask_tensor = torch.ones(inp_tensor.shape)
mask_tensor[mask_row_ids, mask_indices] = 0

output = torch.mm(inp_tensor * mask_tensor, my_tensor)
print(output)


Thanks for the help! But nope! The inp_tensor * mask_tensor operation would results in the elements that I want to exclude to be in the computational graph. So in general, multiplying by 0, while not having an effect on the final tensor, is not good because it will still include these elements in the computational graph
